# Refreshing Bash prompt after invocation of a readline bound command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-prompt, readline

My shell is GNU Bash 4.3.11, and I currently have `M-h` bound to `cd ..` by calling the builtin

```
bind -x '"\eh": "cd .."'
```

This gives me a nifty way to navigate up the directory tree, as I can repeatedly hit `M-h` instead of the incredibly time-consuming `cd ..`. It has the downside, however, either of not resetting my `$PS1` or of not redrawing my prompt, so I lose the context of my current working directory until I enter a new command.

One alternative I'm aware of is to put a macro like

```
"\eh": "\C-a\C-kcd ..\C-m"
```

in my `.inputrc` directly. This, however, has the downside of not only losing the context of any existing command I'm typing in (which I think can probably be worked around) but also of printing out `cd ..` (which I don't think can be).

My desired behavior is to be able to be in a directory `~/one/two` with prompt `~/one/two$`; hit `M-h`; and then be in `~/one` and have the prompt be `~/one$`, ideally keeping any command I had initially. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Figured this out.

```
# maintain state
bind -x '"\200": TEMP_LINE=$READLINE_LINE; TEMP_POINT=$READLINE_POINT'
bind -x '"\201": READLINE_LINE=$TEMP_LINE; READLINE_POINT=$TEMP_POINT; unset TEMP_POINT; unset TEMP_LINE'

# "cd .." use case.
bind -x '"\206": "cd .."'
bind '"\eh":"\200\C-a\C-k\206\C-m\201"'
```

Comment: Note that this breaks many UTF-8 characters (normally 0x80 would be the almost unused C1 range, e.g. for Latin encodings). I'll recommend these replacements: \300\301 \365-\367 \370-\377. (RFC 3629: "The octet values C0, C1, F5 to FF never appear.")

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to that party - and came here looking for that answer also. First of all: As you were the only one providing information on this: thanks for not letting it come to this: https://xkcd.com/979/ ;) instead you pointed me to the on corner in that fractal that seems to hold a solution.

This approach, in my opinion backed up by hours of trying, is the only one where you can a) replace content on the line, and b) execute bash code. Let me offer up some more suggestions to a specific problem:

If you are trying to have it both ways: insert something on the command line, *or* executing code, things can get very tricky. for both, there exist bindings, and I let the reader figure out things with `help bind`. But in the case you e.g. have [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) produce some directory as output, and you'd either cd to it, or have it pasted into your command -- depending on the keystroke done in FZF -- things will get near impossible. you'll face either the not-updated-promt problem, or not be able to execute the cd command in the top shell (where it has effect).

Your solution would be a multiplexing -x binding, inspecting the output for "macros" (get extracted and eval'd) or the default pass-through (manipulating READLINE_LINE/POINT).

Because the solution has some enormity, and the audience may be limited (closed answer...), I'll leave it at a haphazard gist where I pasted my code which works now. To make up for the brevity and uncommented-ness, I welcome any questions in comment or elsewhere. Hope someone may be pointed in the right direction.
 - The code related to this question starts in function `bindInsertEvalWithMacrosVi`
 - It is designed for Vi keybindings but the same principles apply for normal readline mode
 - It depends on some \C-x\C-... combinations to do redrawing in places that are not related to this post.
https://gist.github.com/simlei/032470cfcd23641987f97a96749128d7